# Google Volley JAR file

Tags: jar, android-volley

I have tried creating a `jar` file for the Google `Volley` library but I keep failing. I have tried looking around for the LATEST one, and can't find any. Would it be possible if someone could kindly give me the latest `jar` file if possible.

Would mean a lot,

Thanks

Comment: Get it by adding library dependencies

Comment: It doesn't work - it keeps complaining that `peer not authenticated`

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033402/peer-not-authenticated-when-importing-volley-library-android/36034367#36034367

Comment: try this mcxiaoke's lib : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you can try the [Jar file from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HGUM4c0YwpZFp2aUlnNjJvV2c/view?usp=sharing) or you can use Google Volley source code files in your project as the way I use in [my GitHub sample project](https://github.com/ngocchung/GoogleVolley/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com). Hope it helps!

Comment: The jar file is outdated, I need the latest one please.

Comment: What problem or issue do you have with this file?

Comment: Well its outdated - the `JsonArrayRequest` class only has one constructor as opposed to many. Please is it possible to have one with the latest library because I am struggling to import it via the library

Comment: If so, use the 2nd way, and update JsonArrayRequest.java. That's default with Google's lib. You can also use mcxiaoke's lib to have more constructors

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is to add the following dependency to your app's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

or if you are unable to do so. The other possible solution is cloning the Volley. Clone the repository and then follow this [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) to import it as a new module.

```
git clone https://github.com/google/volley
```